# XML error: AttValue: " or ' expected

Tags: xml

My XML is a bit rusty, but I'm trying to create a local weather web-based api in XML. It is not finished however, but I have run into an error whilst testing it out, which is

> error on line 3 at column 16: AttValue: " or ' expected.

My code:

```
<local_weather>
    <local_counties>
        <county id = 1>
            <name> Suffolk </name>
                <location>
                    api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Ipswich,uk&APPID=6ce0e1da2bbce97fe9e735c3a2009c71  
                </location>
            <name> Norfolk </name>
                <location>
                    api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Norwich,uk&APPID=da4be448d33cb1b0d8b5bdaa4daca4f7
                </location>
            <name> Essex </name>
                <location>
                    api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Chelmsford,uk&APPID&APPID=9fa167ffbd810a6cdbf0fe73597d92fe
                </location>
            <name> Cambridgeshire </name>
                <location>
                    api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Peterborough,uk&APPID&APPID=2dcefd34930d723d95c0c3d910f90c3d
                </location>
  </local_counties>
</local_weather>
```

Comment: How are you generating this? If you use a XML generation library, you'll be guaranteed to always be generating well-formed, legal content. Trying to roll your own is setting yourself up for bugs in the future as content changes over time and exercises new corner cases.

Comment: ...if you let us know which language you're using, we can provide a pointer to a well-supported library that's available for the purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three corrections necessary to make your XML ***[well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085)***:

1. Change `<county id= 1 >` to `<county id="1">`.
2. Add an end tag for `county`.
3. Replace `&` with `&amp;`.

---

Here is your XML corrected to be well-formed:

```
<local_weather>
    <local_counties>
        <county id ="1">
            <name> Suffolk </name>
            <location>
                api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Ipswich,uk&amp;APPID=6ce0e1da2bbce97fe9e735c3a2009c71  
            </location>
            <name> Norfolk </name>
            <location>
                api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Norwich,uk&amp;APPID=da4be448d33cb1b0d8b5bdaa4daca4f7
            </location>
            <name> Essex </name>
            <location>
                api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Chelmsford,uk&amp;APPID&amp;APPID=9fa167ffbd810a6cdbf0fe73597d92fe
            </location>
            <name> Cambridgeshire </name>
            <location>
                api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Peterborough,uk&amp;APPID&amp;APPID=2dcefd34930d723d95c0c3d910f90c3d
            </location>
        </county>
  </local_counties>
</local_weather>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the value of your `id` attribute with a single or double quote.

```
<county id="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to write:

```
<country id = "1">
```

(Note the quotes.)