# XML error on line at column: EntityRef: expecting ';'

Tags: xml

I have encountered another error with my XML. When I try to compile my XML, I get the error

> error on line 7 at column 64: EntityRef: expecting ';'"

I do have it included but for some reason it keeps showing me this.

Here is my code:

```
<local_weather>
    <local_counties>
        <county id="1">
            <name> Suffolk </name>
            <title> Current Weather Listed </title>
            <location>
                api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Ipswich,uk&APPID=6ce0e1da2bbce97fe9e735c3a2009c71; 
            </location>
            <name> Norfolk </name>
            <title> Current Weather Listed </title>
            <location>
                api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Norwich,uk&APPID=da4be448d33cb1b0d8b5bdaa4daca4f7;
            </location>
            <name> Essex </name>
            <title> Current Weather Listed </title>
            <location>
                api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Chelmsford,uk&APPID&APPID=9fa167ffbd810a6cdbf0fe73597d92fe;
            </location>
            <name> Cambridgeshire </name>
            <title> Current Weather Listed </title>
            <location>
                api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Peterborough,uk&APPID&APPID=2dcefd34930d723d95c0c3d910f90c3d;
            </location>
        </county>
  </local_counties>
</local_weather>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must replace `&` with `&amp;` in order for your XML to be well-formed.

(This was correction #3 in the [answer you accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39620951/290085) to your [previous question about this XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39620786/290085).  Why not use the fully corrected XML posted in that answer?)

Comment: I just tried that but I keep getting the same error for some reason.

Comment: Did you get ***all*** of the `&` characters?   I suggest you copy and paste the [corrected XML in my earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39620951/290085) so you're sure not to miss any of the many corrections I made there.

Comment: I just copied what you pasted on the other question, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Never mind, It works now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not have `&` in xml. it has to be escaped. replace your `&` with `&amp;` in your xml and try.